# inserting many ArrayList inside a single structure

Tags: java, structure

as title says i want to know if exist any structure that can allows something like this:

*key = 1 -> arrayList1 , arrayList2 , arrayList3...*

```
someStructure.add(1,arrayList<1>);
someStructure.add(1,arrayList<2>);
someStructure.add(1,arrayList<3>);
```

***IMPORTANT***

the **key** has to remain the same for each list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can roll your own by using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
Map<YourKeyClass, List<Data>> someStructure
     = new HashMap<YourKeyClass, List<Data>>();
```

To your desired situation, looks like you need:

```
Map<YourKeyClass, List<List<Data>>> someStructure
     = new HashMap<YourKeyClass, List<List<Data>>>();
```

Here's a kickoff example of the structure:

```
class MyMapOfList<K, V> {
    Map<K, List<V>> innerMap;

    public MyMapOfListOfList() {
        innerMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        List<V> list = innerMap.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<V>();
            innerMap.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

And you may use it like this:

```
MyMapOfList<String, List<Data>> myMapOfList;
```

If you don't like to add/maintain the `List`s internally in the `Map`, you could use a structure from third party library like [`MultiMap`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava, which behaves more like you want/need.

More info:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: @CiMat no. `Map` is an interface, while `HashMap` is an implementation of `Map`. You may use another implementation like `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: my real intent is to, when i finish to work, i'll delete all values, and i think the map,as you explained works well.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap<Key,Value>` would do it.

**SSCCE:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Map mMap = new HashMap();
            mMap.put("PostgreSQL", "Free Open Source Enterprise Database");
            mMap.put("DB2", "Enterprise Database , It's expensive");
            mMap.put("Oracle", "Enterprise Database , It's expensive");
            mMap.put("MySQL", "Free Open SourceDatabase");

            Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                System.out.println(mEntry.getKey() + " : " + mEntry.getValue());
            }

            mMap.put("Oracle", "Enterprise Database , It's free now ! (hope)");

            System.out.println("One day Oracle.. : " + mMap.get("Oracle"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-hashmap-tutorial-java/